# Does the type of kill matter for promotion?

Tags: xcom-enemy-unknown

The main factor when it comes to promotions seems to be the number of aliens a soldier has killed. Does it matter what kind of alien is killed? Does a strong alien give more experience than a weak one, or are all aliens equal?

Comment: I suspect each alien has an 'xp' value, you gain a portion of that for damaging them and all of it for a kill.  And it takes a certain amount of xp per promotion.  This is solely based on observation (and this remains consistent with previous xcoms) so I'll leave it as a comment until some hard numbers can be dug up.

Comment: I hope this is the case. Now that my main soldiers are getting maxxed, any rookies or less experienced soldiers are not getting kills anymore. Perhaps it would let me promote those guys (slowly) if I took a few potshots at an enemy with my rookies before killing them with the sniper...

Comment: There is definitely an XP chart for promotions - it's even in the data files somewhere in plain text - and it is definitely possible to gain XP without killing, as I've had people become Squaddies with no kills. I can't find any XP values for enemies in the data files, though. That strongly suggests that all of the aliens give XP in the same way - maybe through damage done, with a hardcoded bonus for striking the final blow.

Comment: @jprete: Do you know where this configuration file can be found?

Comment: "Program Files\Steam\steamapps\common\XCom-Enemy-Unknown\XComGame\Config\DefaultGameCore.ini". Or just do a file search for DefaultGameCore.ini. There are plenty of other files in that directory, but DefaultGameCore.ini is the one with most of the interesting gameplay-relevant values.

Comment: Thank you for pointing me to that file. It seems to contain all relevant gameplay information for the aliens, but there doesn't seem to be an exp value. This hints that all aliens are indeed worth the same amount of exp.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

jprete pointed out that there is the file DefaultGameCore.ini which lists all relevant stats of the aliens (as well as a lot of other gameplay stats). The alien data does not contain anything which looks like an exp stat. This heavily hints that all aliens do indeed give the same amount of exp.